# Cant convert bson to json in python 2.7 using bson module

Tags: json, python-2.7, module, bson, converters

Unable to convert to json object from bson file.
bson file : https://s3.amazonaws.com/orim-misc-data/assessment/books.bson

I want to convert Bson file to Json object. But i was getting an exception when i used bson module and the attached file,

```
INPUTF = "books.bson"
input_file = io.open(INPUTF, 'r', encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')
datas = bson.loads(input_file.read())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSON isn't quite a drop-in replacement for JSON.

BSON is a binary object format, not a text format (even though it does store strings UTF-8 encoded)

your opener should reflect binary mode

```
# input_file = io.open(INPUTF, 'r', encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')  # old
input_file = io.open(INPUTF, 'rb')
                               ^
                               | (b opens the file in binary mode
--------------------------------   does not need the rest of the encoding/error params)
```

You'll need to call the [bson.decode_all(data)](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html#bson.decode_all) function rather than load s

```
# datas = bson.loads(input_file.read()) # old
datas = bson.decode_all(input_file.read()) # python list object
```

highly suggest you consider a [bson.decode_iter](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html#bson.decode_file_iter) if your pipeline supports it

```
#datas = bson.loads(input_file.read()) # old
datas = bson.decode_file_iter(input_file) # python generator object
for document in datas:
    # do something with each document
    # very easy on system io and memory
```